# Failure to return variable after series of functions in Python

Tags: python, function, variables, return-value

I am trying to return a variable ('brand') which is manipulated through a series of functions. If I go through the first function (brandSelector) which find an intersection between the variable and array the variable is returned. However, if the secondary sub route is chosen in the event that the first fails then the variable arrives at brandDetectionFailure(), however it is not returned the start (Main() Function). I have tried using 'global brand' but it did not work.  I would appreciate any suggestions on forcing the variable to be returned to the start, rather than receiving None when printing back at the main function.

Note for flow control from main program:
Returns here after following brandSelector() --> brandDetectionFailure() (from exception handler) --> defineBrand()

```
#Import Modules
import sys, warnings, string

#Define Globals
brands = ["apple", "android", "windows"]
brand = None

def init():
    #Define
    #warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") #Disable for debuggings
    #Main Menu
    print("--Welcome to Troubleshooting Applet--")
    print("In your query please include the brand of your device and the problem / symptom of your current issue. \n")

def Main():
    init()
    query = input("Enter your query: ").lower()
    brand = brandSelector(query) #Returns here after following brandSelector --> brandDetectionFailure (from exception handler) --> defineBrand
    print(brand)
    #secondaryMain(query)
    print("END")

def secondaryMain(query):
    #Push required variables to next stage
    print(query)

##START Brand Selection Route
def brandSelector(query):
    try:
        #Format Brands Query
        brand = set(brands).intersection(query.split())
        brand = ', '.join(brand)
        #Check Condition After Setting
        int_cond = confirmIntersection(brand)
        if int_cond == False:
            raise NameError("No Intersection")
            #brandDetectionFailure()
        return brand
    except NameError:
        print("\nNo Intersection found between query defined brand and brands array\n")
        brandDetectionFailure()

def confirmIntersection(brand):
    if brand in brands:
        return True
    else:
        return False
##END Brand Selection Route

##START Brand Selection Route | SUB: Failed Selection
def brandDetectionFailure():
    print("-Brand could not be found-")
    print("Query still stored for your issue")
    if userConfirm("Would you like to redefine a brand and continue?"):
        defineBrand()
    else:
        end()

def defineBrand():
    brand = input("Enter your device's brand: ")
    int_cond = confirmIntersection(brand)
    if int_cond == False:
        if userConfirm("Try again?"):
            defineBrand()
        else:
            end()
    else:
        print("End of Sub Route") #STILL NEEDS WORK
        return brand
##END Brand Selection Route | SUB: Failed Selection

##START Generic Functions
def userConfirm(question):
    reply = str(input(question+' (y/n): ')).lower().strip()
    if reply[0] == 'y':
        return True
    if reply[0] == 'n':
        return False
    else:
        return userConfirm("Please confirm using yes or no")

def end():
    print("Have a good day. Bye.")
    sys.exit()
##END Generic Functions

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: `brandDetectionFailure` doesn't have a `return` statement. And your `except` block in `brandSelector` doesn't have a `return` statement. So nothing gets returned in that case.

Comment: `try/except` is not usually the right way to jump around within the same function, it's for catching errors in functions that you call. You should just use normal `if/else` flow control.

Comment: Hey Barmar, Thanks for your support, I have added in the return statements. Assuming this is correct, when I run the script when I print brand I recieve a blank space. Any ideas? Thanks `def brandSelector(query):
...
    except NameError:
        print("\nNo Intersection found between query defined brand and brands array\n")
        brandDetectionFailure()
        return brand` I could still change to if else, but would that fix the issue?

Comment: I can upload it to PasteBin http://pastebin.com/DwZnQdK7 - Thank you :-)

Comment: It should be `return brandDetectionFailure()`. And `brandDetectionFailure` needs to have `return defineBrand()`.

Comment: Every function needs to return something.

Comment: You are quite simply a legend! Many Thanks! Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With thanks to Barmar (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar),

I followed his solution of:

"brandDetectionFailure doesn't have a return statement. And your except block in brandSelector doesn't have a return statement. So nothing gets returned in that case."

followed by a clarification of

"It should be return brandDetectionFailure(). And brandDetectionFailure needs to have return defineBrand()."

In summary, "Every function needs to return something."